Printing the main header memo of GL Impact in an advanced PDF Template instead of the line memo in NetSuite
I have modified the GL Impact template printout in advanced PDF Netsuite but when using the field {record.memo}, my value returns information in {record.line.memo} , how can i return the main memo on the advanced PDF template separately from the line memo?
<table style="width: 100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 25%" scope="col">${record.trandate@label}</th>
            <th style="width: 25%" scope="col">${label.postingPeriod}</th>
            <th style="width: 25%" scope="col">${label.transactionType}</th>
            <th style="width: 25%" scope="col">${record.tranid@label}</th>
            <th style="width: 9.70877%" scope="col">${record.exchangerate@label}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
     <tr>
        <td style="width: 25%">${record.trandate}</td>
        <td style="width: 25%">${record.postingperiod}</td>
        <td style="width: 25%">${record.type}</td>
        <td style="width: 25%">${record.tranid}</td>
        <td style="width: 9.70877%">${record.exchangerate}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 9.70877%"><strong>${record.memo@label}:</strong></td>
        <td>${record.memo}</td>
    </tr>
</table>

